# Very simple; beginner class

Tags: python, class

New to python and currently learning about classes and OOP. I'm trying to get the following simple piece of code to run but can't figure out why I'm getting an error. Please see code below:

```
class Animal(object):
    fur = True
    def real_animal(self):
        if fur:
            print "Real animal"
        else:
            print "Fake animal"

class Dog(Animal):
    fur = True
    def __init__(self, name): 
        self.name = name

rover = Dog("Rover")
rover.real_animal()
```

I get an error stating fur is not defined. From my understanding, classes can inherit from classes. So, since Rover is-a instance of class Dog, which is a class Animal. Shouldn't I be able to run functions of base class Animal on Rover? I basically want to state dogs have fur and therefore are real animals.

Thanks all for helping a newbie.

Comment: Is your indentation exactly as you have it above? Because that'll cause you problems... everything in the class needs to be indented under the class definition line.

Comment: @Ffisegydd while changing `fur` to `self.fur` inside `real_animal()` will allow the code to run, it's an incomplete fix -- and unless you're going to make `fur` an instance variable (which it seems like you should), you might as well reference it as `Animal.fur` to avoid confusion.  There's also the issue about the random `has_fur` that doesn't do anything at the moment.

Comment: @JuniorCompressor - how do you know that is the code the OP had - perhaps he has messed up his indentation

Comment: @Mark Because he didn't have parse error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two mistakes:

- You need to refer to the fur variable as `self.fur`, because it's not a local variable but a variable on the instance / class
- In the `Dog` class, you call the variable `has_fur`, but in the parent class it's called just `fur`.